# Can't add new monogame content project to solution in VS2012

Tags: c#, windows-7, visual-studio-2012, monogame

I'm trying to add a new MonoGame content project (via templates installed in the MonoGame 3.0 installer) to an existing solution in Visual Studio 2012 (Professional), but it always comes up with the following dialog box:

[image: Error popup]

It does create a few empty folders where the project should be, though they don't have anything in them. After this popup it also comes up with this:

[image: Second error popup]

I do not have XNA installed as VS2012 does not support it.

Also, I am using Windows 7.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i were you I would read the three blog posts that Tara Walker has made about Windows 8 game development starting with this one: [Overview, Installation and MonoGame 3.0.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tarawalker/archive/2012/12/04/windows-8-game-development-using-c-xna-and-monogame-3-0-building-a-shooter-game-walkthrough-part-1-overview-installation-monogame-3-0-project-creation.aspx)

The third blog post talks about creating a Content Pipeline outside of Mono Game (using XNA) and importing it into your MonoGame project. It sounds like you will need XNA so you'll need to read through her information and figure out how to get it working in VS2012 Express.

I've been dabbling with a MonoGame project in my spare time and I have been able to load some textures and sprite sheets without a dedicated content project; everything is just added to the project solution and created during initialization of the main class. But I don't know if this is viable in the long term.

HTH.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using win7, but I looked over that article and it seems to be about what I want, though I'd rather not have to go through XNA when there is supposed to be away to do it all through monogame, especially since I have to install VS2010 to get it working.

Comment: Well, I just found out monogame relies on the XNA content pipeline, so I guess there isn't any way around it for now.

Comment: MonoGame will have support for Content Pipeline projects hopefully in the next release. If you were using Windows 8 you could follow this blog post : http://geekswithblogs.net/Mathoms/archive/2013/01/17/a-recipe-for-integrating-the-xna-gs-content-pipeline-projects.aspx to use VS2012 without having to use VS2010

Comment: @borrillis, still no official content pipeline in 3.2, but maybe in 3.3.

Answer (score -1):

Mono Content Project depends on the XNA as MONOGAME is still working on truly independent CONTENT MANAGER. So as off now we have to intall XNA.  Download it from [XNA zip](https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases/view/117230) and unzip the content because XNA is not officially supported by MS.
Read the attached readme and install as mentioned. Don't forget to intal the file in zip folder named
"XNA Game Studio 4.0 (2012).vsix" which installs the "XNA" template for VS.

Now try to create a sub-project for your content. Your problem should be fixed !!